# How to get (" ") or (' ') in MySQL code editor with a single press?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

First & foremost, I apologize if my question sounds stupid. I am very new to SQL or programming language. On other IDE, say VS Code, if we type  `"` or `'` it automatically shows as `""` or `''` and inside we can type the relevant information. But on MySQL I did not find this features. Is there any way we can enable this? Thanks.

Comment: MySQL is a DBMS. It isn't an IDE, and doesn't take keyboard input. What editor are you using for your SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0. When I use VS Code or SSMS, by typing ' or " it gives '' or "" respectively. But the same feature, I have found in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: I've added the mysql-workbench tag to your post. Being specific helps you get answers more quickly, because it provides the relevant details that are needed. You should take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to better understand how the site works - it will improve your experiences here considerably. It was suggested that you do so when you created your account here, and ignoring that suggestion usually doesn't work out well for new users.